# uiimageview aspectfill issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have layout with multiple imageviews, which look perfect with Mode->Aspect Fill as below.

[image]

now my situation is when I run the same, the whole layout just break into peaces.

[image]

Comment: check clip subviews for imageview

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0, your comment is perfectly solved my problem but **Aerows** give it as answer I have to mark that as answer.

Comment: no problem .. its not about reputation .. its about helping each other .. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each of your `UIImageView` make sure to **enable** `clipSubviews` in Interface Builder.

[image: Clip Subviews]

What happens is that your `view`s are positioned and sized properly, but since the contained `image` is bigger than the containing view it will *bleed out* outside of the view boundaries.

Comment: thanks for perfect explanation, just wanted to know why that would not happened in storyboard and only at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

`aspectfill` is not the issue. The problems is in your `autolayout`. Select all your image views in storyBoard and embed them in stack view with proper constraints.

To achieve this, Select all image view then go to

> Editor > Embed In > Stack View